# Core data entity as dictionary/plist

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I would like to fetch a core data entity, and store its data in a NSDictionary or a plist. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
request.entity = [[NSEntityDescription] entityWithName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:myContext];
request.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
NSError *fetchError = nil;
NSArray *results = [myContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&fetchError];
```

If not using ARC, release retained objects appropriately.